# Move elemnt along the Parent Element on Resize

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, pixelsense

I am new to surface Development which now (Pixelsense). I have and Object or element over the Image in ScatterView. What I want is when a ScatterViewItems gets resized (Zoom), the same way I want Element also get transformed in to the same location and the size should also get changed so that element looks Zoomed.
as I have shown in the picture
[image]
The red box can be resized so the circle also needs to be resized and need to transformed to the new coordinates in the same way.

Comment: Can you just wrap it all in a `ViewBox` or is that not avaliable in `Pixelsense`

Comment: Thanks man it solved my hours of development time.I was thinking to develop on my own effort but you get solution that worked for me :)
I would like to mark as answer but don't know how to do that..